# Which version of Bellman-Ford algorithm is right, CLRS or Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

Code below is from *Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition*.

```
BELLMAN-FORD(G,w,s)
1 INITIALIZE-SINGLE-SOURCE(G,s)
2 for i = 1 to |G.V|-1
3   for each edge (u,v) ∈ G.E
4       RELAX(u,v,w)
5 for each edge (u,v) ∈ G.E
6    if v.d > u.d + w(u,v)
7       return FALSE
8 return TRUE
```

Following is from *Algorithms, 4th edition*.

```
for (int pass = 0; pass < G.V(); pass++)
   for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
      for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v))
          relax(e);
```

It seems that the only difference is the number of passes.

```
for i = 1 to |G.V|-1
```

and

```
for (int pass = 0; pass < G.V(); pass++)
```

Which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: the question was actually about the number of passes on the outer loop: N-1 or N. Bellman's paper linked below states "The functional equation technique of dynamic programming, combined with approximation
in policy space, yields an iterative algorithm which converges after at most(N — 1) iterations."
The justification is given in CLRS in [Lemma 24.2 and its proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaS1i.jpg).

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
for each edge (u,v) ∈ G.E
```

and:

```
for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
  for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v))
```

are equivalent for the purpose of this algorithm: they both iterate once over every edge of the graph. The second version just iterates over all the vertices first, and for each vertex, iterates over its incident edges.

As for lines 5-7 of CLRS they check that there is no negative-weight cycle, but that is apparently ignored in the extract you posted from *Algorithms, 4th edition*. Checking [Bellman's original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/qam/1958-16-01/S0033-569X-1958-0102435-2/S0033-569X-1958-0102435-2.pdf) I don't see this final check, so it may be an addition of CLRS or other .

Comment: The number of passes is the number of iterations of the most outer loop. I just edited the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest path to any vertex in the graph has at most **|V|-1** edges, and reaches at most **|V|-1** verices other than the source.

After the **Nth** run through all the edges, the **Nth** vertex reached along any shortest path is guaranteed to have the correct cost assigned, so the algorithm only requires **|V|-1** passes to account for all shortest paths.